# How to replace cartridge on Grohe shower valve

Tags: plumbing, shower, cartridge

I have a Grohe thermostatic shower valve that runs very hot.  I realize I probably just need to replace the cartridge, but I'm a much better electrician than plumber!  I'm pretty sure the model name is Seabury.  I found the following numbers on it: A112 18.M 0504-51

What are the next steps? I think the black plastic thing needs to come off to get to the cartridge, but I don't want to break anything trying to get it off.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Grohe valve body]
[image: Grohe Seaburry removed cover and handle]

Comment: Hey George, you may want to provide your answer to this. I'm pretty sure that it hasn't been sitting like this for more than a year... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Purchase the replacement, it comes with a tool you will need to remove the cartridge. Before you start turn the water off both hot and cold.

- The tricky part is finding the set screw that holds the handle on the stem. They all have a set screw. Remove the screw and put it in a safe place, I generally use an old prescription bottle.
- Work the handle loose, it may take a bit of jiggling.
- It is possible there is an adapter plate below that, remove that as well.
- Next use the tool and remove the ring, by unscrewing the big nut behind it, the tool pulls the cartridge out. Here is a link showing [how to remove the cartridge](https://www.google.com/search?q=replace+cartrage+on+grohe+shower+valve&ei=a8cJYbG_Gcu4tQb177DoBA&oq=replace+cartrage+on+grohe+shower+valve&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEM0COgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOhAILhDHARCjAhCwAxDIAxBDOhAILhDHARDRAxCwAxDIAxBDOgQIABANOgYIABAHEB46CAgAEAgQBxAeOgUIABCGAzoECAAQHjoGCAAQCBAeOggIABAIEA0QHjoECCEQCkoFCDgSATFKBAhBGABQ27kHWP_XB2Ch3AdoAXACeACAAaUBiAHUDZIBBDE5LjKYAQCgAQHIAQvAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjxoJu595XyAhVLXM0KHfU3DE0Q4dUDCA4&uact=5#kpvalbx=_7McJYaDuAtO5tAaFzpTgCg54)
- Just reverse the process to install the new one. There should be instructions with the replacement cartridge.

Comment: I added some formatting to make this readable. Also, you may consider clicking the search result in Google and sharing the actual link instead of forcing people to be tracked by Google's tracking as they click the search result itself. It also gives a _much_ shorter link. `<Promotion>`DuckDuckGo will give you the actual link in the search results page and doesn't track your searches or clicks.`</promotion>`

Comment: Additionally, a lot of your answer focuses on removing the handle and trim which the OP obviously knows how to do since he provided a pic with those removed. It could be helpful, however, for future readers.